# Focus control after form is shown

Tags: delphi, focus

I have some forms that help me search for a product or a customer. When i open these forms i want the TEdit control that i type into for searching to be focused. I've been using a Timer for that but i've been searching for a more legit way to do this as this causes errors sometimes if the control is told to be focused when the form is not visible yet.

I've tried to use a windows message AfterShow that is called on the end of OnShow event of my Form. It doesn't work as the other simpler solutions of ActiveControl or SetFocus. The window message code is this.

```
const WM_AFTER_SHOW = WM_USER + 444;
  private
    procedure WmAfterShow(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_AFTER_SHOW;

procedure Tproducts_edit_form.WmAfterShow(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
self.ActiveControl:= search_txt;
//showmessage(Screen.ActiveControl.Name);
//PostMessage(search_txt.Handle, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);
end;
```

Strange thing is that if uncomment both the showmessage and the postmessage, the TEdit gets the focus correctly. If i don't, the form opens but the TEdit is not focused even if the Screen.ActiveControl.Name tells me that the control i want has the focus.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make the edit control have `TabOrder` of `0` and that's all you need to do.

Comment: I cannot make it work... made sure the TabOrder property of the TEdit and all it's parent containers have TabOrder := 0.

Comment: I cannot understand that comment. You appear to be talking to yourself.

Comment: The Edit Control has TabOrder = 0, the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Works for me. What's different about your program. You didn't show a program. Just a couple of scraps. This is really the crux of debugging, and your real problem is that you've not learnt to debug yet. Instead of understanding your problem you've just tacked on hack after hack, without gaining proper understanding. So, make a [mcve] to reproduce the issue. Then I predict you'll be able to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, i will try your approach and get back to this.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to use Form.ActiveControl (not Screen.ActiveControl) property to set focus on control, but use it in OnShow, not in OnCreate etc..:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    ActiveControl = Edit1;
}
```

If it doesn't work, maybe because of manual interfering with window message handler, message queue.

Answer (score -1):

The windowsmessage technique is working and the TabOrder of the control to be focused indeed has to be zero.

The problem i had was lying in the DevExpress Bar that my control is docked. The way these bars work makes it impossible to focus a non-DevExpress control that is docked into a DevExpress Bar.

Comment: No mention of that in the question. That's why we should have had a repro.

Comment: Never thought that this could cause such a problem... sign of my limited experience. Thank you for your time

Comment: Always worth while isolating a problem so that you fully understand it. Otherwise you'll solve the wrong problem which is often worse. Simplify simplify simplify!